# Convert one column to standard date format in Python

Tags: python, pandas

For a `date` column I have data like this: `19.01.01`, which means `2019-01-01`. Is there a method to change the format from the former to the latter?

My idea is to add `20` to the start of `date` and replace `.` with `-`. Are there better ways to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If format is `YY.DD.MM` use `%y.%d.%m`, if format is `YY.MM.DD` use `%y.%m.%d` in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['19.01.01','19.01.02']})

#YY.DD.MM
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%y.%d.%m')
print (df)
        date
0 2019-01-01
1 2019-02-01
```

---

```
#YY.MM.DD
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%y.%m.%d')
print (df)
        date
0 2019-01-01
1 2019-01-02
```